# Calculating the height of the binary search tree

Tags: recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

Given the following code:

```
private int getHeight(Node root){
        if(root == null){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            int leftHeight = getHeight(root.leftChild);
            int rightHeight = getHeight(root.rightChild);

            if(leftHeight > rightHeight){
                return leftHeight + 1;
            }
            else{
                return rightHeight + 1;
            }

        }
    }
```

What I don't understand are these two lines:

```
int leftHeight = getHeight(root.leftChild);
int rightHeight = getHeight(root.rightChild);
```

How come does it calculate the height of a tree recursively? What if a tree look like this:

```
     4
    / \
   /   \
  1     9
   \   /
    \ 8
     2
      \
       \
        3
```

How do those two lines calculate it?? And how on Earth does recursion adds `1`while going through a tree?

The way I see it is:

`int leftHeight = getHeight(root.leftChild);` goes to node with `1` and stops there.

`int rightHeight = getHeight(root.rightChild);` goes to node with `9` and stops there.

I just don't understand how it traverses the whole thing.

Detailed explanation would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first sum up the elements we have.

**Stop condition**

```
if(root == null){
        return 0;
}
```

This means that we are on a child which does not exist. For instance, in your tree, the "2" element does have a right child, but does not have a left child. So when you will call

```
int leftHeight = getHeight(root.leftChild);
```

root.leftChild will be equal to null. So we have to return 0, because this child does not exist.

**Recursivity**

```
int leftHeight = getHeight(root.leftChild);
int rightHeight = getHeight(root.rightChild);
```

For each element of your tree, you want to obtain the number of elements before itself on its left and its right. So you are calling the same function, giving in parameter the left child or the right child. If this element does not exist, we enter in the stop condition, and return 0. If there is an element, we want to check the same thing, and continue the same way. That explains why you are able to not just stop at "1" and "9" and continue until you meet a leaf.

**Height calculation**

```
if(leftHeight > rightHeight){
    return leftHeight + 1;
}
else{
    return rightHeight + 1;
}
```

We want to compute the height of the tree. We explained before that leftHeight will contain the number of elements under the actual element on its left, and rightHeight on its right. If there is more elements on the left, that means that the height is greater on the left than on the right. We then return this computed height, and add 1 to it. We add 1 because the element we are on is also part of this height : we want to tell our parent element than the height under it is its child (1), plus all the elements under its child.

**Example**

Now that we have explained everything, let's try with your tree example.

The function will be called on your "4" element, and then will go all the way to the bottom of your tree. Let's start with your "3" element. Because it doesn't have any child on the left or on the right, we will have leftHeight and rightHeight equal to 0. That means that the height under this element is 0. We then just return 1, corresponding to the "3" element.

```
        3
```

We then arrive on "2". "2" has no child on its left, so leftHeight will be equal to 0. But rightChild will be equal to 1, because the "3" element returned this information. 1 > 0, so we will return the value of rightChild (1), and add one for the "2" element.

```
     2
      \
       \
        3
```

We then arrive on the "1" element. Same concept : no child on the left, 1 on the right. leftHeight is equal to 0, rightHeight to 2, because the "2" element returned this information. 2 > 0, so we will return the value of rightChild (2), and add one for the "1" element.

```
  1
   \ 
    \
     2
      \
       \
        3
```

Let's go in the other side now. We have the "8" element. It has no child, and will act like the "3" element. It will then just return 0 + 1 for itself.

```
  1 
   \ 
    \ 8
     2
      \
       \
        3
```

The parent element of "8" is "9". This element has no child on the right, so rightHeight will be 0. But it has one child on the left, "8", which returned him 1. 1 > 0, so we will return the value of leftChild (1), and add one for 9.

```
  1     9
   \   /
    \ 8
     2
      \
       \
        3
```

We then arrive on our final element, "4". It has one child on the right, "9", and one on the left "1". rightHeight will be 2 there, because "9" returned this value. leftHeight will be 3, because "1" returned this value. 3 > 2, so we will return the value of leftHeight (3), and add one for the "4" element.

```
     4
    / \
   /   \
  1     9
   \   /
    \ 8
     2
      \
       \
        3
```

"4" was the root element of your tree, on which your function has been called the first time. In the end, we know that the height of your tree is 4.